# a relation in Prolog to shift elements left rotationally

Tags: prolog

I need a relation in prolog to shift list left rotationally by one element such that

```
?shift([1,2,3],L)
```

should produce

```
L=[2,3,1].
```

could you help me?

Comment: Can you say what you have tried and what problem you are having with the code you wrote?

Comment: @vincent
I am able to write very little.I am not getting any idea after that.
shift(list L):-shift(Tail,L1)

Comment: Can you say what success you've had removing the first element from the front of a list and appending one to the end?  :-)

Comment: Joel is right. Start by simply removing the first element of the list. If that works then you will only have one more problem to solve. Appending an element to the end of a list.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the append command to combine elements of a list together:

```
shift([H|T], Y) :-
  append(T, [H], Y).
```

So you simply append the tail and head together (in that order), and set `Y` to that newly-created list.  Note that since `H` is an element and not a list, you must surround it with `[` and `]` to make it a list in the `append` function.

Also, [here's a good basic overview](http://www.mars-attacks.org/~boklm/prolog/page_7.html) of using lists in Prolog.